# How to configure multiple sites in sub-directories in NGINX server?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have to host two different systems in a nginx server. I have added different location for two different systems like this:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)$ {
       root /var/www/site1/app/resources/public;
}

location ^~ /authentication/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)$ {
      root /var/www/site1/authentication/resources/public;
}
```

There is no error but it works for only one website at a time. if I comment any location, it works which is enabled.

How to configure location for two systems in a single nginx server?

Answer (score 0):

The `^~` operator is **not** used with a regular expression. Use `~` or `~*` for a `location` with a regular expression.

Regular expression locations are **evaluated in order**, so you need to place the more specific rule **before** the less specific rule.

Try reversing the two `location` blocks and change `^~` to `~*`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: I tried ~* and ~ both instead of ^~ but it didn't work.